# Why is proportional editing only effecting one side of my mesh?

Tags: edit-mode, shape-keys

I'm currently working on facial expressions and using Shape Keys and I've just run into this weird problem...

[image]

Whenever I manipulate one side using Proportional Editing, the other side won't follow or match, no matter the size of the fall-off. It's like the other side just stays where it is. I'm not sure what's happened. There are no modifiers active or waiting to be applied, such as the Mirror.

[image]

I can't figure out what's wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Please upload your .blend via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Edited the original post

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to disable the *X Mirror* option in the *Tools Options* panel

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. Everything else has been great using X Mirror to manipulate both sides, so I could do with doing the same here, but it just isn't working properly

Comment: I've downloaded your file and I don't have any problem if I disable the X Mirror and enable the Proportional Editing option, so it's weird

Comment: So if you disable X Mirror and use Proportional Editing, are you still able to adjust both sides at the same time, or are you doing one side at a time?

Comment: The X Mirror option will work as long as Blender finds a symmetric vertex, if  you switch off the X Mirror, move a vertex on a side, you break the symmetry for each vertex you've moved (including the ones that have been moved with the Proportional Editing). What exactly is you goal? Why don't you disable X Mirror?

Comment: I've had to whilst working on the mouth, but I'm trying to do facial expressions with Shape Keys. At the moment I'm trying to do an angry mouth position.

Comment: Why are you using the X Mirror? Also, it's more convenient to use bones, but it depends on your final purpose

Comment: So when changing the expression of the mouth etc., it does it on both sides...? I have the Vertex Groups and Shape Keys set up so I can assign one side of the expressions to its own Vertex Group - Left or Right. I'm following a book and an online guide, which use Shape Keys for the expressions. I'm finding these more convenient than bones, but I think those will be used too following the book.

Comment: if you keep the X Mirror it will symmetrize all the changes you make, but if you make a-symmetrical expression, you won't be able to use the X Mirror on these vertices